# Is it critical to match vacuum pump oil to specific pump?

Tags: equipment

We have rotary vane vacuum pumps of many makes, models, and ages, but superficially they seem remarkably similar. Each has a recommended pump oil (that is, if we can find the documentation); often each different, branded oils. For general purpose use, is it really necessary to keep stocks of the correct oil for each pump? Is there a single pump oil that will work reasonably well for all?

Comment: If one looks at, e.g., Krytox oils, one will find a wide range of viscosities. You need to match that, at the least. Compatibility with any seals is also needed. A chat with an application engineer, or a talk with a local supplier (should you have one) sounds like a good idea.

Comment: In principle yes but if you are just wanting milli-torr pressures any general rotary pump oil should be ok, just purge the pump  first get get rid of whatever has dissolved in the oil by previous users. If its to back a diffusion pump then you really will want the new clean oil.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is critical to match vacuum pump oil to the specific pump. Different vacuum pumps have varying operational requirements and design considerations. Pump manufacturers provide recommendations for compatible oils to ensure optimal performance, longevity, and sealing properties. Using the recommended oil type and viscosity helps maintain efficient lubrication, proper sealing, and prevents potential damage to the pump's internal components. Always refer to the manufacturer's guidelines to ensure the correct oil is used for your specific vacuum pump model.